# Resolving a relationship in xml with Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I wonder if it is possible to resolve a relationship whithin an xml document whith it's related value.

Assume we have the following XML Document

```
  <document version="1.4" date="20150427" time="170326">
    <timeperiods>
        <timeperiod id="TP_1">
            <day>1</day>
            <period>1</period>
            <starttime>0815</starttime>
            <endtime>0900</endtime>
        </timeperiod>
        <timeperiod id="TP_2">
            <day>1</day>
            <period>2</period>
            <starttime>0915</starttime>
            <endtime>1000</endtime>
        </timeperiod>
        <timeperiod id="TP_3">
            <day>1</day>
            <period>3</period>
            <starttime>1015</starttime>
            <endtime>1100</endtime>
        </timeperiod>
        <timeperiod id="TP_4">
            <day>1</day>
            <period>4</period>
            <starttime>1115</starttime>
            <endtime>1200</endtime>
        </timeperiod>
        <timeperiod id="TP_5">
            <day>1</day>
            <period>5</period>
            <starttime>1215</starttime>
            <endtime>1300</endtime>
        </timeperiod>
        <timeperiod id="TP_6">
            <day>1</day>
            <period>6</period>
            <starttime>1315</starttime>
            <endtime>1400</endtime>
        </timeperiod>
        <timeperiod id="TP_7">
            <day>1</day>
            <period>7</period>
            <starttime>1415</starttime>
            <endtime>1500</endtime>
        </timeperiod>
        <timeperiod id="TP_8">
            <day>1</day>
            <period>8</period>
            <starttime>1515</starttime>
            <endtime>1600</endtime>
        </timeperiod>
        <timeperiod id="TP_9">
            <day>1</day>
            <period>9</period>
            <starttime>1615</starttime>
            <endtime>1700</endtime>
        </timeperiod>
        <timeperiod id="TP_10">
            <day>1</day>
            <period>10</period>
            <starttime>1715</starttime>
            <endtime>1800</endtime>
        </timeperiod>
        <timeperiod id="TP_11">
            <day>1</day>
            <period>11</period>
            <starttime>1815</starttime>
            <endtime>1900</endtime>
        </timeperiod>
    </timeperiods>
    <lessons>
        <lesson id="LS_100">
            <periods>28</periods>
            <times>
                <time>
                    <assigned_period>1</assigned_period>
                </time>
                <time>
                    <assigned_period>2</assigned_period>
                </time>
                <time>
                    <assigned_period>1</assigned_period>
                </time>
                <time>
                    <assigned_period>3</assigned_period>
                </time>
                <time>
                    <assigned_period>5</assigned_period>
                </time>
                <time>
                    <assigned_period>10</assigned_period>
                </time>
            </times>
        </lesson>
    </lessons>
</document>
```

Is it possible to select any time element with the starttime beeing displayed of the respective assigned_period?

I tried something like this:

```
document/lessons/lesson/times/time/../../../../timeperiods/timeperiod[period/text() = ./assigned_period/text()]/starttime
```

still no luck... i don't know what i'm doing wrong. if i'm evaluating the following expressions i get the following result sets:

```
record.XPathEvaluate("//timeperiod")
```

--> i get all the timeperiods

```
record.XPathEvaluate("./assigned_period")
<assigned_period>6</assigned_period>
```

I get the correct assigned_period of the current time element.

But if i'm trying to execute the following

```
record.XPathEvaluate("//timeperiod[period = ./assigned_period]")
```

I receive null.
I've also tried the following:

```
record.XPathEvaluate("//timeperiod[period/text() = ./assigned_period/text()]")
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you want this, but such xpath selects starttime of timeperiod tags with period present in assigned_period

```
//timeperiod[period = //assigned_period]/starttime
```

results in:

```
Element='<starttime>0815</starttime>'
Element='<starttime>0915</starttime>'
Element='<starttime>1015</starttime>'
Element='<starttime>1215</starttime>'
Element='<starttime>1715</starttime>'
```

Comment: Hi Splash, Thanks for your response. The problem is that im working on a dataimport where the root of my xPath query is the time node. This means I can easily access the assigned_period. But how can i get the according starttime based on that loaction?

Comment: if mark any time with id=1, such xpath `//timeperiod[period = //time[@id=1]/assigned_period]/starttime` gets the result you want. Maybe, it will work in your case if change `//time[@id=1]` by point. ie `//timeperiod[period = ./assigned_period]/starttime`.

Comment: still no luck... i don't know what i'm doing wrong. if i'm evaluating the following expressions i get the following result sets: 

- record.XPathEvaluate("//timeperiod")
--> i get all the timeperiods


- record.XPathEvaluate("./assigned_period")
-- <assigned_period>6</assigned_period>

But if i'm trying to execute the following
record.XPathSelectElement("//timeperiod[period = ./assigned_period]") I receive null.
I've tried also the following: 
record.XPathSelectElement("//timeperiod[period/text() = ./assigned_period/text()]")